# Anyway to get Database Diagram for sql server 2012 with vs 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

So i have a database in visual studio and now i am trying to get a relationship diagram between the tables.

However on searching the internet it says this feature is not avaiable in sql server 2012.

So is there any way i can extract relationship diagram automatically otherwise i will have to make the whole thing manually which is quite time consuming.

Comment: Can't you just create a diagram from SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of software tools that can create a relationship diagram, such as Microsoft Visio Professional (but *not* Visio standard), or [DBVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/).  The latter is available as a free "crippleware" version that may still do what you need.